# How to disable dots on Kendo UI NumericTextBox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendonumerictextbox

I need to make a numeric field **only
integer**, so that the field does not accept decimals. 
I would **not** even like the field to **approximate**, simply not accepting points or commas.

Based on the culture, it accepts the numeric separator (eg EN is the point, IT is the comma)

Here is the code I tried

```js
$("#numerictextbox").kendoNumericTextBox({
     culture: "en-US",
     step: 500,
     spinners: false,
     format: "#",
     decimals: 0
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.3.1023/styles/kendo.common.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.3.1023/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.3.1023/styles/kendo.silver.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.3.1023/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css"/>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.3.1023/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.3.1023/js/cultures/kendo.culture.en-US.min.js?bust=v21"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
<input id="numerictextbox" />
</body>
</html>
```

Here you can find the link to [dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/ONECAXet/2) with the example of Italian culture, in this case it blocks the comma

Comment: Have you tried changing the format to "{0:n0}"? You can also try "{0:#.##}" if you find that "{0:n0}" doesn't always get rid of the decimal separator.

Comment: They eliminate the decimal separator, but the problem remains. I would not like the new value to be approximated (eg 3.9 becomes 4)

Comment: I wouldn't want them to be able to add it, now as you can try in the examples, it's possible. But I would like to have only integer number, if possible not let the user to insert a separator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using the [restrictDecimals](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/numerictextbox/configuration/restrictdecimals) configuration option.

```
$("#numerictextbox").kendoNumericTextBox({
    culture: "en-US",
    step: 500,
    spinners: false,
    format: "#",
    decimals: 0,
    restrictDecimals: true
});
```

With this configuration a comma and a point with behave like entering a letter(red exclamation flash).

[Example](https://dojo.telerik.com/@Stephen/AsIzufoF)